# Show that $(a, b) \mapsto a + b + pab$ makes $\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$ into a cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'd like to show that $(\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}, \ast)$ is a cyclic group, where $\ast$ is defined by $$a \ast b = a + b + pab$$

I have already proved this, but in a way that is unsatisfying: I simply checked that the given operation satisfies the group axioms, and proved by tedious calculations the order of 1 with respect to this operation is equal to $p^n$.

I feel like there ought to be a way to simultaneously show that $\ast$ is a group operation and that the resulting group is cyclic. It reminds me of the following question:

> Show that $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}, \star)$ is a group, where $\star$ is defined by $$a \star b = ab + a + b$$

where the "right" way to prove this is to observe that $ab+ a + b = (a+1)(b+1) - 1$, and so $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}, \star)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \times)$ but we have renamed $x$ to $x - 1$.

I wonder if there is a similar argument for the first question that avoids all of the manual work I did.

Comment: You are working with a nilpotent scaling factor $p$. Notice that $1+p(a*b) = (1+pa)(1+pb)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, and it's indeed very similar. We can write

$$p(a \ast b) + 1 = (pa)(pb) + pa + pb + 1 = (pa + 1)(pb + 1)$$

so now the isomorphism we want is

$$(\mathbb{Z}/p^n, \ast) \ni x \mapsto px + 1 \in (1 + p \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}, \times)$$

where $1 + p \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}$ is the subgroup of the (multiplicative) group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}$ consisting of elements congruent to $1 \bmod p$. This gives the group axioms immediately but it still takes a little bit of work to show that this group is cyclic, although that's a classical argument, closely related to the existence of [primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I'm already happy that the multiplicative subgroup is cyclic (except for p=2 which deserves special attention).

Comment: @Sam: yeah, it seems this argument implies the result isn't true when $p = 2$ and $n \ge 2$, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.